# iPhone SDK: How to go about a Translator style app

Tags: iphone, sql, database, switch-statement

i'm trying to make an app that can basically take text from one box, as entered by the user, and convert it into an equivalent of that text into another text box.
When I say equivalent, I mean another way of wording that same word, these would be my own words, and not available on some other database that's already been done somewhere.

I could do this on a small scale with something like a switch statement for all the given possibilities, but for a whole language this has practicality issues.

How would I go about doing this? Would I database all of the words and their equivalents in an SQLite database? And how would I integrate this into an app? I have very limited knowledge when it comes to programming that would include a whole database of values, i'm just used to listing separate values, and am not really aware of the short codes capable of integrating a lot of values.
Is it possible to integrate all of the values of an SQL database into a Switch or if statement, that could separate a user's text entry, into the separate words it contains, and display their equivalents as listed in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your "these would be my own words, and not available on some other database that's already been done somewhere" comment, is it correct to assume your word-for-word replacement is a valid approach to what you want to achieve? (no separate language or precedent to what is right?)

If so, I think you would do something like:

1) take the string from the input field, 
2) apply componentsSeparatedByString: to it to have it broken into an array, then, 
3) take each item in the array, search your sqlite DB for it, return the equivalent word, and append that to a string (and a space)...
4) when you're done with the array, output the resulting string to the 'output' box.

SQLite is pretty easy to work with, you can just start with a big excel file, then with some sqlite manager (I use a firefox plugin), import that into a .sqlite file, and add that to your project. Have you thought about how you would handle 'word not found'?

This is untested code, just to give you something to start with:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
}

-(sqlite3 *) getNewDBConnection{
        sqlite3 *newDBconnection;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
        // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
        if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened"); 
        } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database");
        }
        return newDBconnection; 
    }

-(void)translate{
        //take input and break into an array
        NSString *clearText = [[NSString alloc] init];
        clearText=inputBox.text;
        NSArray *words = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        words= [clearText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        numOfWords=words.count;
        NSString *newText=@"";
        //open database
        sqlite3 *db = [self getNewDBConnection];
        //loop through array
        for(i=0;i<numOfWords;i++){
            sqlite3_stmt *resultStatement = nil;
            NSString *res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from dictionary where plain='%@'",[[words objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [res UTF8String], -1, &resultStatement, nil))!=SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Error getting result, maybe word not found\n");
                        NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }
            else{
                if(sqlite3_step(resultStatement)==SQLITE_ROW){
                    //in the line below, 1 is the column number of the replacement word
                    NSString *add = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (char*)sqlite3_column_text(resultStatement,1)]
                    newText=[newText stringByAppendingString:add];
                    [add release];
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(resultStatement);
        }
        //output result
        outputBox.text=newText;
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {

    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    //NSLog(@"Creating editable copy of database");
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well, i've been trying to implement this code for an hour or so, and on the log side of things, I keep getting the "Error getting result, maybe word not found" message, I can only think my problem is with the actual database file that i've made, what is there that i can troubleshoot here?

Comment: did you change 'dictionary' to the actual table name that you used in your sqlite file? and 'plain' to the correct name of the column you used?

Comment: I realized just because we broke up the string at spaces, they're still THERE...so instead of searching for 'word' you were probably searching for 'word ' or ' word'...I added a trim in the above code: `[[words objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet]`

Comment: Well, if I only tried one word, with no spaces, shouldn't it still work? Because thats what i've been trying, i haven't even gotten onto multiple words, and also the compiler complains of whitespaceCharacterSet as being undeclared

Comment: yes, it should have worked with one word. here's where I got that set: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:

Comment: so how did you create the sqlite database and add it to your project? and how about adding another log of the query so we can see if that part is built correctly (I've done so to the above code)

Comment: I created it in terminal, The column plain is of the type TEXT, and the translation is also of the type TEXT, and the table name is dictionary. The sqlite database is simply in the resources area. The logs are now as follows: 2011-05-31 17:32:18.112 Concept[7153:207] Database Successfully Opened
2011-05-31 17:32:18.113 Concept[7153:207] Error getting result, maybe word not found
2011-05-31 17:32:18.114 Concept[7153:207] tried query:select * from dictionary where plain='word'

Comment: what if you try that query in the terminal? how did you populate your table?

Comment: When i try that query in terminal it appears to work, it displays word|translation, and I populated the table in terminal using this command: INSERT INTO dictionary (plain, translation) VALUES ("word","translation");

Comment: okay, I swapped out the 'tried query' log with this `NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));` which might shed some light

Comment: Mhm interesting, it logs " error: no such table: dictionary", but then why would the terminal query work?

Comment: in simulator, delete the app...maybe it's a sync issue? I would have expected that you'd get a DATABASE error if that were the case, but it's worth a shot

Comment: Interestingly if I set the path to the database to something that doesn't exist, the errors exactly the same...

Comment: I didn't think you needed it because you wouldn't be writing to the database, but I added the `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` method (and called it from viewWillAppear)...maybe give that a shot?

Comment: I added that, and it still doesn't work, and the logs are the same.

Comment: I'm pretty stumped...that it gives a 'successful open' regardless of the DB name is very odd. the code in `(sqlite3 *) getNewDBConnection` is common (googling it gives multiple examples)...maybe post a different question specific to that element? someone else might know where to look for causes? Sorry I don't know where to look.

Comment: Well, i've been looking through lots of examples on the net of SQlite integration, and I cant seem to see any issue with the code, so i've decided to post another question, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Machine translation is an extremely complex problem, and **cannot** be solved simply by implementing a word-by-word dictionary translation. Wikipedia has a decent overview of the different approaches extant in the literature; note, however, that none of them are trivial to implement.

[Machine translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation)

Comment: Yes, for actual languages maybe, but for my app, it's suitable, as it's more like a different way of wording the same word.